# How to specify JPA 2.1 in persistence.xml?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.1, persistence.xml

A quick search on the Net reveals three or four variants how folks have been specifying `xmlns` and `xsi:schemaLocation` in `persistence.xml`.

What would be the 'correct' manner to specify JPA version 2.1?

I'm using

```
<persistence version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
```

Comment: Configuration file OCD... welcome to the club.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr338/index.html) it must be (like yours):

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    ...
</persistence>
```

Comment: +1. @kmansoor As an addition, to point out the exact place where this configuration is shown, one can see the related XSD file (starting from line 50): http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd