# JPA 2.1 no work in eclipse kepler

Tags: persistence, eclipse-kepler, jpa-2.1

this tag doesn't work in eclipse kepler and wildfly 8.0, want to work with jpa 2.1 the tag is auto generate by eclipse.

```
<persistence version="2.1"  
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence     
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
```

if I try with this tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
```

everything works fine.

please helpme with this issues.

[image: this is the error]

Answer (score 0):

According to this reference: [How to specify JPA 2.1 in persistence.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142168/how-to-specify-jpa-2-1-in-persistence-xml) your tag seems fine.

Can you please post the error eclipse is giving for JPA 2.1 tag?